# I want to colorize cells base on the previous value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a formula where the cell color changes based on the previous value. For example, if D2>C2 then I want the color to be green. If it's lower, then red. If same value, then yellow. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

- open up conditional formatting
- enter the range you want to apply it
- select from dropdown "custom formula"

use for green:

```
=($D2>$C2)*($D2<>"")*($C2<>"")
```

for red:

```
=($D2<$C2)*($D2<>"")*($C2<>"")
```

and for yellow:

```
=($D2=$C2)*($D2<>"")*($C2<>"")
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I prevent the empty cells to stay uncolored? Also, about yellow, I wanted it to turn yellow if D2=C2 or if it's the same value.